# Realtek Audio Drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, hardware, alsa, realtek

Are there any Realtek audio drivers for Ubuntu? If yes where do I get them and how do I install them correctly? *(for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)* Also with jack work okay after I install them?

**Curious about the reason?** The ALSA drivers don't support microphones for my soundcard (Creative Sound Blaster 5.1 VX). Also, It does not handle audio output quite well. I have issues. Also, I'd really like some software like the windows-only "Realtek Audio Manager" that does effects to the audio such as echoes and so on.

Comment: The drivers for Realtek hardware are already part of the kernel.

Comment: @CL. I see. ...I want to read more about this. (the realtek drivers being part of the kernel). Do you have anything for me?

Comment: Same issue here, only left speaker is working

Comment: @Batousik it's a good thing that it works. [try this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316804/sound-only-works-from-left-speaker/599082#599082)

Answer (score 22):

The best thing to do would be to remove alsa and reinstall it. The same thing happened to me when I switched motherboards, and this fixed it.

1. Remove the ALSA packages.

   ```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
   ```
2. Reinstall the same packages.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
   ```

   Packages gdm and ubuntu-desktop are also removed in this process if you are using Gnome. They need to be reinstalled:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gdm ubuntu-desktop
    # or 
    sudo apt-get install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   If you are using Xubuntu this will also happen to you.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gdm xubuntu-desktop
   ```
3. Reboot.

   ```
    sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Thanks but no that doesn't work. The driver is just not there. I've even tried various distros and the mic just doesn't work so far on any of them.

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading my ubuntu 14.04 :) thanks.

Comment: `gdm has no installation candidate` on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks worked for me on ubuntu 21.10 with latitude 9420

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (internal mic not working) with my Lenovo Ideapad 320, which runs Ubuntu 18.04.

I installed GNOME ALSA Mixer from the Ubuntu Softwares Panel and followed another topic instruction: put the "Capture" full on the right and "Internal" empty on the left, as the following image:

[image: see this screenshot]

It worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install Pulseaudio Equalizer for purposes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Your sound card Realtek may have problems frequencies. To solve install OSS. It seems that [it is supported](http://manuals.opensound.com/devlists/Linux.html). Download from [here](http://www.opensound.com/download.cgi). Install and restart.

If installation errors, install `alsa-oss`

There is a similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803761/low-sound-quality-in-linux-for-ever-in-realtek).

Comment: The kernel maintainers want to remove OSS from Linux in the near future and I have doubts that OSS supports recent products from Creative or Realtek while looking the the list in one of your links.