# Low sound quality in Linux FOR EVER, in Realtek?

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek

I wonder why that is and why such poor sound quality? I have searched the various Free Software communities and even installed as the ordering on its website located here:http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

My sound card is ALC662 rev1. I also use Windows 10 and the sound is excellent there.

I know this sound card is not Free Software, but can not find the solution to my problem, hardly it sounds a little better when I place the connector on the front of the computer, but the back of the sound is "stinky" and as the General.

I've tried several players as Rhymtbox, VLC, Totem, etc. and all the same.

A bad Some default settings? I do not know, here I leave an image capture running "alsamixer" in terminal. I hope you is enough and I expect a prompt response from you, thanks atemano.

[image]

Ronal Plata

Comment: «here I leave an image capture running "alsamixer"» Where is it?

Comment: English Google Traslate: I found solution. Apparently the problem is ALSA frequencies.

And I downloaded OpenSound (OSS) from here: http://www.opensound.com/download.cgi Now the sound is excellent, best!

Install and reboot, although I think reboot is not necessary.

Comment: Español: Encontré SOLUCIÓN. Al parecer el problema son las frecuencias de ALSA.

Y he descargado OpenSound (OSS) desde acá: http://www.opensound.com/download.cgi Ahora el sonido es excelente, ¡de lo mejor!

Instalar y reiniciar, aunque creo que reiniciar no es necesario.

Comment: You should post this as an *Official* soultion

Comment: Please do not post `[SOLVED]` in the title. You can post an answer to your question.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Sorry, english bad!

Comment: You can post your solution to the Answer box below the comment box.

Comment: [SOLVED] Read up.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer. Please write a self-answer including the essential steps (not just a link).

Comment: Wow! Update kernel of the new release of Canonical and "BUM" good sound went to hell again, and now I can not install OSS again and apparently it is advisable to install a system based on Arch Linux system because if you give support OSS. What do I do? I do not want to install another system just because of ALSA?

Comment: @RonalPlata alsa is part of ubuntu now. if you don't want to install to another system to use a different sound engine, you will have to revert to a version of ubuntu that would let you uninstall alsa.

arch is nice. it's not *too* intensive to set up if you refer to a tutorial.