# Is there any audio-driver for ubuntu gnome 17.04 to increase sound volume level and quality?

Tags: drivers, sound, 17.04

This is the info from `sudo lspci -v`

> 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

```
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio 

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 128

Memory at b1428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Memory at b1410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]

Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3

Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

I have tried installing oss and i get this error:

> OSS build environment set up for REGPARM kernels
>
> Building module osscore ld: Relocatable linking with relocations from
>   format elf32-i386 (osscore_mainline.o) to format elf64-x86-64
>   (/lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/oss/osscore.ko) is not
>   supported Linking the osscore module failed

Also tried, installing `pulseaudio-equalizer` from this post [Realtek Audio Drivers for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722685/realtek-audio-drivers-for-ubuntu) but didn't solve the problem.

If anybody have any other idea, please suggest.

**Edit #1:**
This is the screenshot of alsamixer.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low sound level is most likely to be due to level settings in ALSA or Pulseaudio. 
If Pulseaudio is set higher than 100% will cause distortion in sound. Combine that with a low level setting in ALSA and you get low volume and distortion.

Use `pavucontrol` Pulseaudio Mixer to check Pulseaudio levels. Panel volume controls and other mixers don't always show all the control options.

Use command `alsamixer` in terminal to check/adjust ALSA levels. There are other audio mixers that show ALSA levels, but posting a screenshot of alsamixer will be best option to get more help

Comment: Increasing sound over 100% in pavucontrol also helped.

Answer (score 2):

In the default Sound panel, increasing the output volume over 100% in the Output tab for "Speakers-Built in Audio". The maximum volume is 153% which is high enough for listening normal videos/songs.