# Bug with videos on Ubuntu 23.10 only when headphones are plugged

Tags: video, headphones, 23.10

Recently updated from Ubuntu 22 to 23.10. When I use my headphones, all videos with audio are broken. When I open a youtube video, the video stops and starts loading, at the same time the audio goes crazy, it loops the first seconds of the video. Similar thing happens with spotify. Someone know how to help me?

Edit: For now reinstalling alsa after update solved the problem, like here: [Realtek Audio Drivers for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722685/realtek-audio-drivers-for-ubuntu)

Edit: Stopped working again after boot. I really don't understand what's the problem, maybe my headphones are incompatible?

Comment: Do the headphones work with other applications?

Comment: did you install `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: @graham it was already installed

Comment: @waltinator Just tried again with spotify, with music it works fine, everytime an adv starts it does the same loop like on youtube. What other application could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Headphones are hardware.  Try running various video etc. without the headphones - VLC and browers don't really know if your headphones are plugged in.  Now if you're using some sort of blue tooth connectivity, that would be a different question. It is my understanding that VLC, browers etc. cannot determine what is plugged into the 3.5 mm audio output jack - nor do they care.

Comment: Without the headphones I don't have any problem. Only when headphones are plugged it breaks. And I do not use bluethoot with these headphones. So you say that vlc cannot determine if headphones are plugged or not? Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm at a loss to explain how plugging simple headphones into the audio output jack would cause the problems you mention.  When you discover an answer, please post it here.

Comment: Reinstalled pulseaudio, now it magically works, but the audio is low :( 
Better than nothing